# How to align node labels in tikz vertically if one of the labels has a superscript?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, alignment

I've faced a problem trying to align vertically labels of 2 nodes. One of the labels has a superscript and that's why the label is not at the same level with another one.

Here's the code to show what I mean.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, shape=circle, node distance=1.5cm, line width=1pt, minimum width=1.5em]

    %Creating Blocks and Connection Nodes
    \node at (0,0) (input) {${\widetilde{X}}$};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
    \node at (sum) (plus) {{\footnotesize$+$}};
    \node at (1.5,-1) (noise) {$Z$};
    \node at (3,0) (output) {$X$};

    %Lines
    \draw[->] (input) -- (sum);
    \draw[->] (noise) -- (sum.south);
    \draw[->] (sum) -- (output);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to align $\wildetilde{X}$ and $X$ vertically. To be more exact, I would like to have both $X$ and $\wildetilde{X}$ aligned by their bottom. Thanks!

Comment: I would use `{$\vphantom{X}\smash{\widetilde{X}}$}` for the input node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use `[anchor=base]` and add a `\vphantom{X}` node on the left to get the correct vertical spacing and a `\hphantom{\widetilde{X}` to get the correct horizontal spacing:

```
\node  [anchor=base] at (0,0)  {$\widetilde{X}$};
\node  [anchor=base] at (0,0) (input) {$\vphantom{X}\hphantom{\widetilde{X}}$};
```

which yields:

[image]

### Note:

- I replaced the `\tikzstyle` with `\tikzset` which should be used instead: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{sum/.style={draw, shape=circle, node distance=1.5cm, line width=1pt, minimum width=1.5em}}

    %Creating Blocks and Connection Nodes
    \node  [anchor=base] at (0,0)  {$\widetilde{X}$};
    \node  [anchor=base] at (0,0) (input) {$\vphantom{X}\hphantom{\widetilde{X}}$};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
    \node at (sum) (plus) {{\footnotesize$+$}};
    \node at (1.5,-1) (noise) {$Z$};
    \node [anchor=base] at (3,0) (output) {$X$};

    %Lines
    \draw[->] (input.east) -- (sum);
    \draw[->] (noise) -- (sum.south);
    \draw[->] (sum) -- (output);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Another possibilities: defining `text height` and `text depth`:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
   sum/.style = {shape=circle, draw, line width=1pt, 
                 node contents={\huge$+$}},
N/.style = {text height=2ex, text depth=0.5ex}
            }
% nodes
\node (in)      [N]             {$\widetilde{X}$};
\node (sum)     [sum, right=of in];
\node (out)     [N,right=of sum]  {\vphantom{$\widetilde{X}$}$X$};
\node (noise)   [below=of sum]  {$Z$};
% lines
\draw[->] (in)      -- (sum);
\draw[->] (noise)   -- (sum);
\draw[->] (sum)     -- (out);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]